# How to know the animation has been finished when called reverse() in Android

Tags: android, animation

I create a ValueAnimation such as follow:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@integer/animation_duration"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:propertyName="alpha"
android:valueFrom="1.0f"
android:valueTo="0.0f" />
```

and then, I create a custome View, and use following code:

```
Animation animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext, R.animator.miss);
animation.setTarget(this);
```

I use start() to let the animation start, but in some case, I want to use reverse() to let the start reverse animation.
I know , when called start(), we can use AnimatorListener and override onAnimationEnd() to know that animation is finished.
So, how call I know the reverse animation is finished when I called animation.reverse() ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try this method yet, but it may be the solution:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAnimationEnd()

Comment: thanks for you help, but I just create a Animator as a member in custome view. the animation you said didn't have reverse().